# Загрузка фотографии в альбом VK (php)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться с загрузкой фотографии в альбом пользователя

1. Получаю адрес сервера для загрузки нормально
2. Далее на этот адрес я отправляю POST-запрос:

   ```
   $curl = curl_init($serverArray['upload_url']);    
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);   
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);    
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'file1=' . file_get_contents($photo));    
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('file1: ' . $photo, 'Content-Length: ' . filesize($photo)));    
   $result = curl_exec($curl);    
   echo $result;
   ```

Жду, что придет ответ вида `{"server": '1', "photos_list": '2,3,4', "aid": '5', "hash": '12345abcde'}`

Но получаю: `{"server":307908,"photos_list":"[]","aid":1,"hash":"1bcf3646f0f6233cb2698cd90cd1f038"}`

т.е. Без списка фотографий

В чем ошибка?

`$photo` - путь до фотографии на сервере

Comment: @iamsalnikov, Ваше решение может еще пригодиться. Расскажите о нем.

Comment: @Iranda, да тут все понятно в общем то передан неправильно параметр:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'file1=' . file_get_contents($photo));    
надо заменить на
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file1'=>@$photo));

Comment: @binliz Это стоит написать как ответ и зааксептить его.